# icomoon.ttf on Worpress shows 404 and long response time slowing down my website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, web, wordpress-theming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BacBP.jpg)

Is there any way to disable or delete this font on my website?

I'm using Azure Web Services to host and Wordpress for editing.

Answer (score 0):

simply locate the icomoon folder in your project directory and remove it. Login via FTP and do the same.